# git commit trigger to block byte order mark

Tags: git, awk, sed

I'm on Windows and sometimes edit files with Notepad, which likes to put a BOM at the start of the file (EF BB BF). It's easy overlook this in the diff and commit to Git a Python file with such a BOM, which I've found will not work on Mac.

I want to create a commit trigger that removes the BOM before committing. Or at least rejects the commit.

The best I've come up with is the script below which I put in 'pre-commit'. It removes any BOM but only after the commit, so then I have to make a second commit.

```
#!/bin/sh
git diff --cached --diff-filter=ACMR --name-only -z *.py | xargs -0 -n 1 sh -c '
    for FILE; do
        sed -b -i -e "1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//" "$FILE"
    done
' sh
```

I tried to use commands and 'q' like this so the exit code would be 1 if it matched, but it doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/sh
git diff --cached --diff-filter=ACMR --name-only -z *.py | xargs -0 -n 1 sh -c '
    for FILE; do
        sed -b -i -e "1 /^\xEF\xBB\xBF/ {s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//;q1};q0" "$FILE"
    done
' sh
```

Can someone help fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track.

A good general rule for a pre-commit hook is not to modify the index contents (i.e., "don't change the commit or work dir, nor even try") but rather just to fail the commit, so your second block of code is probably closer—but you're still modifying the files.  You *can* do this if you want, and you can even `git add` them as well if you *really* want.  It's just generally not a great idea: it tends to be too surprising, and it does unexpected things with carefully staged versions that deliberately differ from the work-directory versions (as produced by `git add -p` for instance).

You also have two options here: you could inspect only new and modified files (which is what your `--diff-filter` is for); or you could inspect every file in the index.  If you'd like to allow any existing (but unmodified) file to retain an existing Unicode-BOM you definitely want the new-and-modified-only method, so let's stick with that.  I'll retain the `*.py` as well, but we want to protect it from the shell so that it uses git's idea of files whose name ends with `.py`, not the shell's.  In particular, that means that if some `.py` files exist in the index—and will therefore be committed, if the commit proceeds—but are not in the work directory, they will get checked.

We can simplify the diff filter a bit, by adding `--no-renames` to the `diff` command so that `R` status cannot occur.  We also know that `C` should not occur since we did not supply any `-C` or `--find-copies-harder` options.  Thus, we start with:

```
git diff --cached --no-renames --diff-filter=AM --name-only -- '*.py'
```

I've taken out the `-z`: `-z` is good if we can use `xargs -0`, but I'm planning to read the file names one at a time instead, since most of these commands really only work on one file at a time.  (It's possible to do that with `xargs` too, but if none of your file names contains a newline, we'll be OK without it.)  The `--` separates diff options from paths (this seems like it should not be required, but see comments below; and it's generally a good idea anyway).

This produces a list of files to be inspected, so now let's inspect (but not edit) them.  If you're on Windows, you may need to modify the below to use whatever limited tools you have; since I'm always on a Linux or Unix box I use `head -1` to get the first line, and `grep` to check for the BOM:

```
#! /bin/sh
git diff --cached --no-renames --diff-filter=AM --name-only -- '*.py' |
(status=0; while IFS= read path; do
    if git show ":$path" | head -1 | grep $'^\xEF\xBB\xBF' >/dev/null; then
        echo "Error: file '$path' starts with Unicode BOM.'"
        status=1
    fi
done
exit $status)
```

Here are the various tricks:

- We set `IFS` to nothing during the read, to allow other kinds of white space.  (For methods that work with `-z`, and hence handle newlines too, see [Etan Reisner's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31443291/git-commit-trigger-to-block-byte-order-mark/31443728?noredirect=1#comment50857013_31443728) below.)
- We use `git show ":$path"` to extract the version of the file that's in the index.  This may (as with `git add -p`, for instance) differ from the version of the file in the work-directory.
- We use `head -1` to discard all but the first line.
- We use `grep` to check for the BOM, which we make with a shell string expansion (`$'...'`), with grep's output directed to `/dev/null` so that it doesn't show up (`grep -q` also works but only if that particular grep supports `-q`).
- We go on to check all listed files, even if some have a BOM.
- To work around the shell's subshell-action with pipes (`cmd | while ...` runs the `while` in a sub-shell), we set the status in an explicit (parenthesized) sub-shell and exit that sub-shell with that status.  That propagates the sub-shell's status—success if no BOMs, failure if some—up to the main shell, where it can become the result of the git hook.

Note: the above is not tested as a complete hook (though I believe it's correct).

Comment: `-z` is just safer and `read` can handle that just fine with `-d ''` so you might as well use it. The only caveat is that if the input doesn't *end* with a `\0` then you have to use `while read -d '' path || [ -n "$path" ]; do` to catch the last line where `read` returns false for `EOF` but you still have contents. Additionally, to be safe for files with leading/trailing spaces in their names you should either use `while IFS= read path` or `while read` and use the automatic variable `$REPLY`.

Comment: Also, using process substitution (`<(...)`) to feed the `while read` loop would mean you don't need the sub-shell games and your `status` variable exists in the main shell and you can work this into an existing/etc. script without problems.

Comment: this is great, thanks! much clearer than my attempts with awk/sed. I only had to make one change, I needed a '--' before the '*.py' else I get 'fatal: ambiguous argument "*.py": unknown revision or path not in the working tree.'

Comment: @EtanReisner: those are handy if you have bash.  I have some systems were I don't want to depend on that, and `-d` is not available in `read`.  The `IFS=` is a good idea though; I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

You could run a filter to strip the BOM on add:

```
git config filter.strip-bom.clean "sed '1s/^\xef\xbb\xbf//'"
git config filter.strip-bom.smudge cat

echo '*.c filter=strip-bom'  >> .git/info/attributes
```

and so forth for other patterns.  Putting it in `.git/info` makes it strictly repo-local so you have a completely free hand.

If you're not on a GNU/ I think sed might not handle the escapes, the filter text is doublequoted so you could sub in `$(printf '\xef\xbb\xbf')` to get it.

Keyboard-to-editbox warning, but I think the syntax is right.